# is there an easy way to do onColdBoot() or onApplicationExit() in android

Tags: android, callback

Sorry if this is a duplicate; I searched for everything I could think of that related to this but couldn't find anything.

In android, I am aware of an activities lifecycle. (`onPause()`, `onResume()`, `onCreate()`, etc) But these don't apply to the application as a whole. Is there an onPause() when the user totally leaves the application? Not just when the user navigates to a different activity but leaves the whole application?

I am wondering mainly saving and loading data purposes. The only way I could think of doing this without the system telling you is some kind Class that manages which activities have called `onPause()` and if all of them have then you know that the user has left the app. If there was an `onApplicationExit()` method I wouldn't have to resave all the user data anytime any one of my activities calls onPause(), only when the user actually leaves the app.

Besides an `onApplicationExit()` method for the application, I am wondering if there is an `onCouldBoot()`, this would be helpful for loading up data. I know that is what your launcher activity is for, but considering that onCreate() is called by default upon screen orientation change makes me wonder if loading up data should be somewhere else...

My question is **are there any callbacks for onApplicationExit or onColdBoot?** and if not then **What are the common practices for loading and saving data efficiently?**

Comment: can you tell me for which case you want loading and saving data efficiently?

Comment: I am just using `PrintWriter` and `BufferedReader`, and it is just basic saved data for the next time the user opens the application

Comment: You can you background service for that. If your task is not related to UI then use Intent Service otherwise bind Background Service

Answer (score 0):

No there is no any method or call back like onApplicationExit or onColdBoot. If you want to continue sync online updated data then you can use [sync adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)